# Onsen UI and AngularJS: change "page"

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using Angular JS with Onsen UI framework. In any template to "change page" I just need to put an ng-click calling the function:

```
ons.screen.presentPage('mypage.html')
```

I need to do the same into a controller (javascript code), in other words I want to change page without clicking on links.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call any function defined into the Screen Service I just needed to add $rootScope before ons.screen.presentPage('mypage.html').

```
$rootScope.ons.screen.presentPage('mypage.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function normally, as you would do outside ng-click.
If you did load onsenui.js, it shall work seamlessly.